# Python program won't write all information to .txt but it will to the shell

Tags: python, text-files

Python program won't write all information to .txt but it will to the shell

```
from time import sleep
import platform, os, sys
log = open("reportLog.txt", "w") 
log.write("####REPORT####\n")


try:
    sys =("SYS: " + platform.system()+ ("\n"))
    syslog = log.write(sys)
    syslog()
except:
    pass
try:
    os = ("OS: " + platform.os()+ ("\n"))
    oslog = log.write(os)
    oslog()

except:
    pass
try:
    platform = ("PLATFORM: "+ platform.platform()+ ("\n"))
    platoformlog = log.write(platform)
    platofrmlog()
except:
    pass
try:
    mac_ver("MAC_VER: " + platform.mac_ver()+ ("\n"))
    mac_verlog = log.write(mac_ver)
    mac_verlog()
except:
    pass
try:
    dist =("DIST: " + platform.dist()+ ("\n"))
    distlog = log.write(dist)
    distlog()
except:
    pass
try:
    node = ("NODE: " + platform.node()+ ("\n"))
    nodelog = log.write(node)
    nodelog()
except:
    pass
try:
    arch =("ARCHITECTURE: " + platform.architecture()+ ("\n"))
    archlog = log.write(arch)
    archlog()
except:
    pass
try:
    machine =("MACHINE: " + platform.machine() + ("\n"))
    machinelog = log.write(machine)
    machinelog()
except:
    pass
try:
    cpu =("CPU: " + platform.processor() + ("\n"))
    cpulog = log.write(cpu)
    cpulog()

except:
     pass
log.write("##########")
log.close()
```

Comment: Welcome. Could you post the content of the file in the question, or is it completely empty? See [ask].

Comment: Thank you to all for this, fairly tired when writing this code, cheers guys :)

Comment: Hi @Hobnob. If one of the answers below has solved your problem please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problems with your code are:

1. you repeat yourself unecessarily
2. `except: pass` is always wrong
3. platform.os is not a function type

The concise and correct version of the code is

```
import platform

with open("reportLog.txt", "w") as log:
    log.write("####REPORT####\n")

    names =  """dist system platform mac_ver dist node architecture 
        machine processor""".split()

    for name in names:
        label = name.upper()
        getter = getattr(platform, name)
        value = getter()

        log.write('{}: {}\n'.format(label, value))

    log.write("##########")
```

I make a list of function names in platform that you want to call and then iterate through those names. I have removed 'os' from the names because `plaftorm.os` is just a reference to the module `os` and I assume that is covered by `system`

For each name, I generate the label by upcasing it. For each name, I get the function with that name from the platform module. To get the return value of calling that function I call it. I use the more common way of putting together a formatted string and write it. Because the open is wrapped with a context manager, it will close the file for me when the context manager ends.

I catch no exceptions because I don't expect any. If there are any exceptions, there is a bug in my code and I want to know about it as dramatically as possible. Uncaught exceptions will ultimately crash the program and print a nice backtrace so I can see where I screwed up. Silently ignoring exceptions is kinda like duct-taping the mouth and nose of a crying baby, it does quiet things down for the moment only to create a worse problem in the future (dead baby).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing the information in tuples, use normal strings. For example:

```
sys = "SYS: " + platform.system()+ "\n"
syslog = log.write(sys)
```

Even better you can use the format function to have a cleaner code:

```
sys = "SYS: {0}\n".format(platform.system())
syslog = log.write(sys)
```

Also, make sure to catch the exceptions to get an idea of the cause of the problem:

```
try:
    sys = "SYS: " + platform.system()+ "\n"
    syslog = log.write(sys)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the problem that *msw* stated, I don't understand why you do something like this:

```
syslog = log.write(sys)
syslog()
```

`log.write` does not return any value (or *None* value to be precise). Yet, you assign that *None* to a variable and execute that variable as if it is a function.

My solution is simpler than that of *msw*, at the cost of being longer:

```
with open("reportLog.txt", "w") as log:
    log.write("####REPORT####\n")
    log.write('SYS: {}\n'.format(platform.system()))
    # Other log.write lines here...
    log.write("##########")
```